# Controlling Apache-Kafka and Flink through SCALA (Not Command Line)

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

Using Kafka/FLink command line - "commands " in SCALA Code

Currently When I submit jobs to Flink, its through the command line. Same as for creating and Deleting Kafka Topics.

Is there an Scala - API for controlling the execution of command line Interface commands. So based on a condition in an application I can submit a job to flink and create/delete kafka from the code.

Commands I would like to use in Scala Code

```
Starting Flink Server
    bin/start-local.sh

Stopping Flink Server
    bin/stop-local.sh

Submitting Job Flink
    bin/flink run -c pathToMainClass pathToJar arg1 arg2

Creating topics in kafka

Deleting kafka topics

Cancelling a job (ID)
...
```

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flink's REST api can be used to [submit](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/monitoring/rest_api.html#submitting-programs) and [cancel](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/monitoring/rest_api.html#job-cancellation) jobs.

For creating and deleting Kafka topics, I would look at [Kafka's Admin API](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/core/src/main/scala/kafka/admin/AdminUtils.scala).

As for APIs for controlling Flink's services, you might be better off waiting for the [ongoing work on FLIP-6](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-4319) to be completed.

Comment: Thank You, That's the direction I needed